# What is the best solution to handle Keyerror Exception in python

Tags: python, keyerror

I have a simple class as below:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        first_dict :  {'author': 'Author', 'status': 'Status'}
        second_dict :  {'Author': 'owner', 'Status': 'current-status'}
        third_dict :  {'owner': 'author', 'current-status': 'status'}
obj = Test()
```

I want to handle if my code wants to access any dictionary with the wrong key as below.

```
obj.second_dict['some_wrong_key']
```

Please note that `second_dict` is dependent on 1st and `third_dict` is dependent on 2nd.

Comment: You would use a try, except. How you handle it is defined by what you want to do.

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking, you handle a `KeyError` like any other exception by using `try: ... except KeyError: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` function. It will return `None` if the `key` not found. Also, it takes an optional argument that will be returned if the `key` is not found.

```
obj.second_dict.get('some_wrong_key')  # returns None (no error)
obj.second_dict.get('some_wrong_key', "I'm missing here")  # returns "I'm missing here"
```